# get address/pointer to a class method

Tags: matlab

I am using Matlab and I want to make a method work with various Matlab versions. So, I have something like:

```
v = VideoReader('Video.mpg');

% Check if a particular method exists
if any(strcmp(methods(v), 'getFrame'))
   % if the method exists, store it in a variable
end
```

Now what I want to do is that if this method exists i.e. if the statement above returns true, I want to store a handle to that method in a variable and be able to call it on the VideoReader object. However, I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Have a look at anonymous functions and also at `feval`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [str2func](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2func.html):

```
if any(strcmp(methods(v), 'getFrame'))
   % if the method exists, store it in a variable
   h = str2func('getFrame');
end
```

Then call `h` the same way you would `getFrame`.